# Why setTimeout is not working in nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, server, settimeout, setinterval, cyclic

I am using node js for my server where i am using setTimeout. It is working fine in my local server but when i deploy it stop working.

```
function StartReactionAndComment({ postObj }) {
    console.log("Start Reaction and Comments");
    console.log(postObj.length)
    for (const post of postObj) {
        console.log(post)
        setTimeout(() => {
AddReactionToPost(post).then((res) => { MaintainPostData(res, null, post.postURN) });// for maintaining post data
        AddCommentToPost(post).then((res) => { MaintainPostData(null, res, post.postURN) });
        console.log("Reaction and Comment added successfully ");
        }, 15000);
    }

    console.log("End Reaction and Comments");
}
```

I am expecting that this function (StartReactionAndComment) call AddReactionToPost & AddCommentToPost after a certain interval of time but it is not working as expected.
I tried different things like node corn, setInterval ect.
Note this code works fine in local server but not in actual server
Currently I am using free server **Cyclic**

Comment: "it stop working"? Well, you might want to look at any log output from your deployment.

Comment: I tried adding logs but not getting any logs on the server as I already said it is working fine locally.

Comment: If you don't have any visibility to what's happening on the server, there's no way we can help either.